# How to test for a boolean field in a twig template?

Tags: theming, 8, entities

`field_boolean` is a boolean field.

`{% if content.field_boolean == true %}` or `{% if content.field_boolean == 1 %}` or `{% if content.field_boolean == 'true' %}` or `{% if content.field_boolean == '1' %}` don't work.

How do I test if the checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to look at the raw value, not the render array.

Example:

`{% if node.field_foo is not empty %}`

This checks if the field exists. The render array won't be useful beyond rendering values.

Don't look at `content` - that is simply the render array. Look at the fields in your entity object (node, paragraph, etc). You might want to install Twig XDebug to breakpoint your templates or inspect variables in `mytheme.theme`.

You *should* be able to look at `{% if node.field_foo.value ... %}` for equality checking.

Comment: How do I check the raw value? 'content.field_boolean.value' doesn't seem to work. Also see my other question about rendering raw values (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/getting-raw-field-value-in-twig-template)

Comment: Don't look at 'content'. Look at the fields in your entity object (node, paragraph, etc). You might want to install Twig xdebug to breakpoint your templates or inspect variables in mytheme.theme.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved the question. If you want to post the same answer to the other question, that might be helpful to other users. Otherwise I'll answer it myself.

Comment: Just another question: is it more efficient to directly use node.field or paragraph.field instead of content.field aside the twig template?

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved this, it requires the [twig_field_value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value) project.

For the boolean field, set the on and off values to 1 and 0 respectively.

In twig:

`{% if content.field_foo|field_raw('value')|number_format(0,'.',',') is same as('0') %}
  <span>the box is NOT checked</span>
{% endif %}`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.


 `{% if '1' in  content.field_name.0 %}
    {{ "anything" }} 
  {% endif %}`

[Source](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2017-03-29/how-to-use-an-if-statement-on-boolean-values-in-twig)