# Hide/Show fields value in nodes

Tags: 8, nodes, entities

I have a content type = Article. There I have 2 field. What I want is, If field 1 is empty or does not contain any value, replace this field with field 2, (with same css and html structure) else keep showing content of field 1 by default.

Is there any way to this in D8?

Comment: you have to put some conditions like if field is null then field 2 will show

Comment: I don't think you would get any contributed module for such task. But this is easily doable by few lines of code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create **node--articles.html.twig** and place it in your theme's templates folder.

```
{% if content.field_name.0 is empty %}
    <div class="something">{{ content.field_name_other }}</div>
{% else %}
    <div class="something">{{ content.field_name }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

**Note:**

- `content.field_name.0` gets the [raw value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-to-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template/228393)