# How do I calculate field_1 + field_2 in Twig?

Tags: theming, entities

I have two fields. `{{ content.field_1 }}` is 2; `{{ content.field_2 }}` is 5.

How do I multiply them to obtain 10, in a template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `{{ content }}` are render arrays which produce the output "2" and "5", but you can't do arithmetics with these render arrays.

You can try to do this with the database values from the node (if it is a node template):

```
{{ node.field_1.value * node.field_2.value }}
```

Comment: does `node.field_1.value` not have html markup? surprised this worked, without getting the "raw" value.

Comment: @NoSssweat, `.value` is the raw value from the database. Or do you mean the raw filter, which would switch off any escaping or xss filtering?
 First this is not supposed to be used for database fields and second for numbers it wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Wouldn't this sort of thing belong in a preprocess instead?

Comment: @4k4 I mean raw filter, but of course don't use that, probably [node.field_1.value.0](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-to-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template/228393#228393) or `| striptags` would result non markup value. Cause I thought `node.field_1.value` would print something like `<div class="something">2</div>`