# twig if Term ID is something, then do something

Tags: theming, 8

I have a taxonomy called Fish and 2 terms in it. Bass and Gold. I have a term reference field on a Page node, and its a select list. The editor can select either Bass or Gold. And I want display something depending on what the user selects. I cannot get it to work. This is what I have tried. Below the Bass tid is '1'.

```
{% if node.field_term_reference.value == '1' %}
  <p>The value is Bass</p>
{% else %}
  <p>The value is Gold</p>
{% endif %}
```

Below I am outputting the string value bass.

```
{% if node.field_term_reference[0]['#title'] == "bass" %}
  <p>The value is Bass</p>
{% else %}
  <p>The value is Gold</p>
{% endif %}
```

Both of these return "The value is Gold"
I tried this also

```
{% if node.field_term_reference.label == "bass" %}
 <p>The value is Bass</p>
{% else %}
 <p>The value is Gold</p>
{% endif %}
```

What if you want to add multiple terms and use AND OR "bass" and "finch".

```
{% if node.field_term_reference.entity.label == "bass" and or "finch" %}
```

How would it be written?

Comment: @paulcap1 please stop editing Answers into the question - you can add an answer for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original question is how to use the term id in a twig condition. You find the term id in the property `target_id` of the reference field:

```
{% if node.field_term_reference.target_id == '1' %}
  <p>The value is Bass</p>
{% else %}
  <p>The value is Gold</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This won't work if there is more than one value for field_term_reference.  Only the first target_id in the array is returned by node.field_term_reference.target_id.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the value of `node.field_term_reference[0]['#title']`  in reality it's `<div class="something">bass</div>`; therefore, your condition is false every time. Same for the other two.

Thus, in your condition you need to get the raw (no markup) value of the field. See [How do I get the raw field value in a template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-template/228393#228393)

This should work:

```
{% if content.field_term_reference.0 == '1' %}
  <p>The value is Bass</p>
{% else %}
  <p>The value is Gold</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here if anyone needs it.

```
{% if node.field_term_reference.entity.label == "bass" %}
 <p>The value is Bass</p>
{% else %}
 <p>The value is Gold</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This isn't the term ID?

Comment: Meaning, the label/name of the term can always change, the term id won't. Soon as the name changes, it breaks the logic.

Comment: @Kevin, Your right it would be better to use the tid. I tried {% if node.field_term_reference.0 == '1' %} but it always return false? I am not able to even print the tid.

Comment: @paulcap1, I've added my comment as answer with a code example.