# How to get the values from a formatted field in inc file

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a description field with a CK editor enabled. And when I get the data from it as `node->get('fieldname')->getString()` it outputs the content as below.

> The contents that I have entered in the Ck editor
>
> , basic_html

I can resolve this in the twig file by getting this as `{{fieldname| raw}}`. But I need to get this in a php file. How do I get the value without that **, basic html** part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I get the value without that , basic html part?

`$node->field_name->value;` should do the trick.

---

> I can resolve this in the twig file by getting this as `{{fieldname|raw}}`.

Using `| raw` filter in twig is bad security practice, see [How do I get the raw field value in a twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template/228393#228393) for a safe solution.