# Call preprocess_node (or get variables) from Twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I have the following content types (for a simple LMS) defined:

- `Lessons`, for which there are rather complex rules for handling view access.
- `Courses`, which contain entity references to one or more `Lessons`.

Now, in the Twig template for rendering a `Course` node, I am trying to create a "table of contents" (a list of `Lessons`), using the following snippet:

```
<nav id='toc_lessons' class="list-group">
  {% for key, lesson in content.field_lessons %}
    {% if lesson['#node'].title.value|render|striptags|trim %}

        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
           href="{{ url('<current>') }}/?lesson={{ lesson['#node'].nid.value }}">
          {{ lesson['#node'].title.value }}
          {{ (*****) ? '<span class="label">LOCKED</span>' }}
        </a>

    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

This works well. However, the problem with this code is the line that I marked with (*****): I would like to do a simple access check, i.e. I would like to **check, if the user is allowed to view the `Lesson`**. If not, the label "LOCKED" should be added.

In my implementation of function `THEME_preprocess_node` I have already defined such a check that is called whenever a `Lesson` is rendered:

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  ...
  $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
  $variables['viewaccess'] = $node->access('view');
  ...
}
```

But **can I call the preprocessing function** for a `Lesson` from within the `Course` template to receive the variable `viewaccess`?

Another idea would be to modify the above snippet as follows:

```
<nav id='toc_lessons' class="list-group">
  {% for key, lesson in content.field_lessons %}
    {% if lesson['#node'].title.value|render|striptags|trim %}

        {{ bamboo_render_entity('node', lesson['#node'].nid.value, 'toc_entry') }}

    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

so, I am now rendering the `Lesson` using Bamboo Twig and the output `<a>...</a>` is fully handled by the `Lesson` template, which works fine. The problem now is that a Lesson that the user does not have view access for, is **not rendered at all**.

Now, I'm stuck. Can anybody offer any ideas?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close. I think there are a couple of approaches to this. This is what I would do

preprocess the lessons entity reference field for the courses bundle, iterate through the values, check the access, set a variable with the access value for each item. Then in field--field-lessons.twig.html, render the field if the access value is true.

```
<?php
//the name of your lessons entity reference field on courses
function THEME_preprocess_field__field_lessons(&$variables) {

  if($variables['element']['#bundle'] == 'courses') {
    $account = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $ent_refs = $variables['element']['#items']->referencedEntities();

    foreach ($ent_refs as $key => $ent_ref) {
      $check = $ent_ref->access('view', $account);
      $variables['items'][$key]['my_access'] = FALSE;

      if ($check) {
        $variables['items'][$key]['my_access'] = TRUE;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

**then in field--field-lessons.twig.html**

```
...
{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.my_access == TRUE %}
      I'm Unlocked: {{ item.content }}
    {% else %}
      I'm locked :(
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
...
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of preprocessing the field. That sounds like a good idea, thank you very much. Will check and report back.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I tried your suggestion and it really does seem to work (i.e. I'm able to use the variable added in *THEME_preprocess_field* to output a "LOCKED" label)... until I also try to output, say, the title of the locked item: Using `{{ item.content['#node'].title.value }}` in *field--field-lessons.twig.html* for a locked lesson prints out nothing (and, even more surprisingly, makes the `for` loop immediately jump to the next item). Any idea, why this happens? Can't I access and print a field's content, if the current user doesn't have view access to the node? Seems weird.

Comment: Hm, seems like you should be able to. Try accessing the title this way in twig: `{{ item.content['#title']|raw }}`

Comment: Thanks again. I ended up simply storing the title (and a few other fields) in variables (within *THEME_preprocess_field*) so that I can access them in *field--field-lessons.twig.html*. Probably not the easiest solution and I'm still unsure, as to why that is necessary in the first place. But that's stuff for another question... :) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @MattCampbell **It is bad security practice to use the `|raw` filter**. As when you use this filter Twigs auto escaping is no longer used. See [How do I get the raw field value in a twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template/228393#228393) for proper/safe way to do it.