# |slice filter does not work with special characters

Tags: theming

I try to use the **slice** filter in order to limit a link to a specific amount of characters. The field that I render is a link field and my code is the following:

```
{% set title_text = title|render|striptags %}
<span> 
     {{ title_text|length > 65 ?
         title_text|slice(0,65)  :
         title_text|striptags}}
</span>
```

Unforturnately some characters like the apostrophe are not rendered appropriately.

So instead of rendering "I've learned", they render "I& #039;ve learned"

Answer (score 1):

Actually the culprit is `|striptags`

> The problem with using twig's **|striptags** is double encoding of html entities,
>   not markup, so & becomes & and then &amp; – Berdir
>
> <sub>source: [How do I get the raw field value in a twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template/228393#228393)</sub>

If your setup relies on you running striptags last, you will need to do this all of this magic in a preprocess function with php setting a variable here and then printing your formatted variable on twig.