# how to just print the value of author in node template

Tags: 8, theming

There are some variables like author_name in node.html.twig of Drupal 8. `{{ author_name }}` will print something like below:

```
 <div><span><span>Basic</span></span></div>
```

I tried using codes like below:

`{{ author_name.0 }} plan to print: Basic`

or

`{{ author_name|field_value }} plan to print: Basic`

Above codes NOT work. How can I achieve above result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most cases [How do I get the raw field value in a twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template/228393#228393) will do. But since here according to [node.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21templates%21node.html.twig/8.2.x)

> author_name: **Themed** author name field.

I believe you can get the unthemed author name by using `{{ node.getOwner.getDisplayName }}`

Comment: I have tested for this case (get the unthemed author name): {{ node.getOwner.getDisplayName }} works; {{ node.getOwner.getDisplayName.0 }} NOT work.