# how to get values for my content type drupal 8

Tags: theming

i have a problem to get values in my twig for my content type , i have just the '{{content}}' variable with a lot of  arrays , how can i get for example my field 'field_image' ?

```
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if label %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}
  {% block content %}
    <div{{ content_attributes.addClass('content') }}>

      {{ content }}


    </div>
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Drupal answers. Your question seems a bit vague to me, can you please clarify what you're trying to achieve? Did you know you can control the fields of a content type in `Structure > Content Types > Manage Display` ?

Comment: i can get the field but not structured in term of css , i want for example to classify them in table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the raw field value in a twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template)

Comment: Please have a look at the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module to structure certain fields in certain wrapper divs with customizable attributes. Please do yourself and future maintainers of your project a favour and don't solve this with printing raw field values in node or page templates. As this will invalidate the admin UI and is a pain to maintain later.