# How can you separately get the name and the value of a field?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to get the key and the value of my row for example I have this:

```
{{ content.field_nom }}
```

but the out put is:

> my field name
>
> my value

My question is how do you get 'my field name' alone and 'my value' alone?

Comment: 'my field name' is probably in `content.field_nom.label`.  For value see [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/228393/89581)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the raw field value in a twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use the node object to render field values and labels seperately.

```
{{ node.field_nom[0].label }}
{{ node.field_nom[0].value }}
```