# Twig escapes tags when using raw value in template

Tags: theming

I am printing fields in a node template, but Twig is escaping my tags and ruining my day.

My `.tpl` looks like this:

```
  <blockquote>
    <p class="title">{{ content.field_myfield.0 }}</p>
  </blockquote>
```

I want to strip all tags from the original field and then "wrap" the field in a paragraph tag with the `title` class.  I found out how to get the raw value without tags based on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/228393/5147).

However, this is the HTML that is actually output:

```
<blockquote>
  <p class="title"></p><p>When you wish upon a star</p><p></p>
</blockquote>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: content.field_myfield.0|render|striptags|trim . Can we try something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code below:

```
{{content.field_myfield.0|render|striptags|trim}}
```

> render:  The striptags filter strips SGML/XML tags and replaces
>   adjacent whitespace by one space.  You can also provide tags which
>   should not be stripped:

```
{{ content.field_myfield.0|striptags('<br><p>')}}
```

trim: The trim filter strips whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string:

```
{{ '  I like Twig.  '|trim }}

{# outputs 'I like Twig.' #}

{{ '  I like Twig.'|trim('.') }}

{# outputs '  I like Twig' #}

{{ '  I like Twig.  '|trim(side='left') }}

{# outputs 'I like Twig.  ' #}

{{ '  I like Twig.  '|trim(' ', 'right') }}

{# outputs '  I like Twig.' #}
```

The example above used from the twig website.