# How to get field value from paragraph entity in twig?

Tags: theming

Is it possible to **get the value from the field inside the paragraph in the red rectangle**.
This code part is placed within a twig-template "`field--block-content--field-example.html.twig`"

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ dd(item.content) }}
  {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

[image: twig item.content print out]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the raw field value in a twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template) If the screenshot shows `item.content` then `entity` (from the linked answer) == `item.content['#paragraph']`

Comment: Yes indeed, `item.content['#paragraph'].field_is_custom_package.value` is working.

Comment: The suggested link is not completely answering my question. Without your comment the suggested link could not have resolved my question. Now I understand that `entity` can be seen as `item.content['#paragraph']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the raw value from an entity:

```
{{ entity.field_example.value }}
```

Where `entity` can be seen as `item.content['#paragraph']`

In my case:

```
item.content['#paragraph'].field_is_custom_package.value
```