# Check if a field is empty inside a twig paragraph template

Tags: theming, paragraphs

I know how to check if a field is empty in a twig template (example node--lorem.html.twig):

```
{% if node.field_lorem.value is not empty %}

    <p>not empty</p>

{% else %}  

    <p>empty</p>

{% endif %}
```

I would like to check if a field is not empty inside a paragraph twig template (example `paragraph--lorem.html.twig`). But this doesn't work :

```
{% if content.field_lorem.value is not empty %}
```

or

```
{% if node.field_lorem.value is not empty %}
```

I can display this field value like this :

```
{{ content.field_lorem }}
```

Comment: Why the downvote ? I could improve the question if I know why.

Comment: [How do I get the raw field value in a twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template) - Replace `node` with `paragraph`

Comment: @Hudri No, I just want to check if a paragraph field is empty or not. I don't want to get the raw value.

Comment: `{% if paragraph.field_lorem.value %}`, not `node`. Not `content`. `content` contains only fields that have been added to the display of your entity.

Comment: @leymannx Thank you. It works perfectly. Can you post your answer ? I will accept it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you could improve the question, because the example you are quoting doesn't match with the question title. You are relying on that the field value evaluates in true or false, which is not the same as the field being empty or not. For this you can use [isEmpty()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21Plugin%21DataType%21ItemList.php/function/ItemList%3A%3AisEmpty)

Comment: @4k4 I understand. I thought `{% if node.field_lorem.value %}`  was similar to `{% if node.field_lorem.value is not empty %}`. I changed the question, is it better?

Comment: You don't need to get the field value first. You can check the field object itself and then this works for any field type, also for those not using the property name `value`. I've added a code example as answer.

Comment: @4k4 Thanks very much. It is much clearer for me and I will be able to improve my code with your answer (I did not know `ItemList::isEmpty`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if a field is empty use [ItemList::isEmpty](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21Plugin%21DataType%21ItemList.php/function/ItemList%3A%3AisEmpty)

**Node**

```
{% if node.field_example.isempty %}
  <p>Field is empty</p>
{% endif %}
```

**Paragraph**

```
{% if paragraph.field_example.isempty %}
  <p>Field is empty</p>
{% endif %}
```