# Applying trim to paragraph value

Tags: 9, paragraphs

I have the following Paragraph template which displays a heading with a trailing orange dot. The field itself is a normal text field in Drupal. For some reason, there is a trailing space after the heading, which leads to a space between the heading and the dot. I want to remove it (and |trim is the answer), but when I add trim to the below variable I get a PHP warning saying parameter 1 should  be a string, not an array.

How do I then get the absolute value of the paragraph value?

```
{% block paragraph %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {% block content %}
      <h1>{{ content.field_heading_h1 }}<i class="orange">.</i></h1>
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

The following gives the PHP error:

```
{% block paragraph %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {% block content %}
      <h1>{{ content.field_heading_h1|trim }}<i class="orange">.</i></h1>
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
> twig_trim_filter()

Answer (score 0):

As the warning states, content.field_heading_h1 is a (render)-array

you could check it´s structure using `{{ kint(content.field_heading_h1) }}` (devel-module)

probably you can get the plain text value and trim it with:

```
{{ content.field_heading_h1.value|trim }}
```

or

```
{{ content.field_heading_h1.0|trim }}
```

refering to [How do I get the raw field value in a twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template)

thats just one way to do "operation on symptoms" but the actual question to ask is why there is a whitespace and is there a way to prevent that already in the form that saves it