# Why precisely the twig raw filter is unsecure?

Tags: theming

Why precisely the twig raw filter is insecure in the drupal context?

What would be an example of a potential threat ?

And what need to be done on the ckeditor field format side to protect potential malicious code, if the raw filter is used ?

Comment: This is all documented: https://www.drupal.org/docs/security-in-drupal/writing-secure-code-for-drupal

Comment: See [How do I get the raw field value in a twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template/228393#228393) to do it safely.

Answer (score 4):

Twig templates escape special characters to prevent potential hacking. Twig raw puts out the data without escaping it, meaning that if it is user-supplied data, it's insecure and could be used for hacking.

Comment: is the admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html limitations and filter not protective enough ? would u have an example ?

Comment: There are multiple levels of filters. Twig filters are just one of them.

Comment: @Matoeil, when you have filtered with a text format you don't need `|raw` because the filtered markup is already marked as safe.